# How to fix an SQL syntax error when defining a function

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

I have a simple function which tries to find the customer id from the driver's licence id. If the driver's licence id exist in our system it returns the customer id. If the driver licence id does't exist in our system it inserts it and returns the customer id. However, I have a sql syntax error which I can't figure out.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_GET_CUSTOMER_ID;

CREATE FUNCTION F_GET_CUSTOMER_ID(P_LICENCE_ID BIGINT)
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_ID BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT id INTO V_ID
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE LICENCE = P_LICENCE_ID
    LIMIT 1;

    IF V_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN V_ID;
    END IF;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO CUSTOMERS (LICENCE) VALUES (P_LICENCE_ID);
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();

END;
```

The error I check is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: Such as the function is not defined because it failed to create them, you just have to fix the creation script then run again, and you will have good function. If you case, you seems to declare variable too late, in plpgsql for example, you have to do it between `return` and `begin` statement

Comment: The function code is correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16363ff1fe3f33e92bd89ca6cbaf4dcc Maybe you forget about DELIMITER?